# Calculating null space of a matrix using c#

Tags: c#, matrix, vector, null

I tried to calculate the Null space of the matrix using Kernel() method of MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra as below:

```
public static Matrix<double> NullMatrix(this Matrix<double> matrix)
    {
        var vectors = matrix.Kernel();
        var rows = vectors.First().Count();
        var columns = vectors.Count();
        var result = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(rows, columns);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = vectors[j][i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But I am getting only number of rows and columns correctly. Values in the result matrix are wrong/different than what I am expecting. Can you please provide me a code to calculate a Null space of the matrix using c#?

For Matlab Null() function, you can refer: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html

For MathNet Library functions, you can refer to: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html

Comment: @JonasH, Matlab function null( ) gives the null space of matrix. I want to get the same output as that of Matlab in C#. I hope you have understood my question.

Comment: I have updated the question with the links. It is saying that Kernel method of MathNet is giving the null space of the matrix. But it is giving the different values in the matrix than the Null function in Matlab.